# After refresh the Dropdown list disapper

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am  getting  Dropdownlist properly but after Refreshing the page all values in dropdown list is disapper.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function SecondLogin(Request $request){

  $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
                ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';

    if (view()->exists($view)) {
        return view($view);
    }
        $email1=session::pull('shop_id');
        $employee_email=session::pull('employee_email');

        $main_shop=User::with('user_details')->where('email', $email1)->first();
        $employee_list=session::pull('employee_list');
        $employee_list = User::Orwhere('id',$main_shop['id'])->Orwhere('shop_parent_id',$main_shop['id'])->where('status',1)->get();


     return view('auth.secondlogin')->with([ 'employee_list'   => $employee_list,'email1'=>$email1,'main_shop'=>$main_shop,'employee_email'=>$employee_email]);
}
```

view 
:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <select name='employee_Id' class="form-control">
                <option class="category" value="" >-Select your name-</option>
                @foreach($employee_list as $employee)
                        <option class="category" value= "{{ $employee->id }}" @if($employee_email==$employee->email) selected='selected' @endif>{!! $employee->name !!}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
```

Not understand what is going wrong. any help will greatly Appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The session pull is deleting the element from the session, so the second time those values pulled from session are null.

(By the way you should avoid logic and database queries directly inside your controller, move them to repository classes)